# Is swyping less repetitive strain injury-prone than typing?

Tags: cellular-phone, repetitive-strain-injury

The two main kinds of silent input on a phone are [swyping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swype) and typing. Is Swype less [RSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repetitive_strain_injury)-prone than typing?

---

- RSI = repetitive strain injury
- Swype = virtual keyboard for touchscreen smartphones and tablets originally developed by Swype Inc. where the user enters words by sliding a finger or stylus from the first letter of a word to its last letter, lifting only between words.

Comment: If you don't leave a comment I cannot clarify...

Comment: Are you talking about "swiping" or Swype the product?

Comment: @DaveL Swype the product (looks like my comment has been deleted)